# How to use Groovy's TableLayout valign attribute

Tags: groovy, tablelayout, swingbuilder

The TableLayou in Groovy's SwingBuilder package supports vertical alignment. But it seems to have no effect when I use it in my code

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;

def ui = new SwingBuilder();
def frame;

frame = ui.frame(title: "Window", bounds: [0, 0, 500, 500], layout: null)
{
   tableLayout(size:[400,400],border: BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 2))
   {
       tr
       {
           td(valign:'top')
           {
               label(text:"Label", border: BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 2))
           }
       }
   }
}
;
frame.show();
```

the label appears vertically centered instead of being located at the top. Are additional atrributes required for proper alignment, or doesn't it work at all with TableLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

The `align` and `valign` attributes of TD only take effect on merged columns or rows that have been merged with `colspan` or `rowspan` attributes. It's pretty much the same behavior as for HTML tables.

The `TableLayout` class is nothing other than a panel that uses the `GridBagLayout`. Every table cell (TD) is just the component added to the panel, with specific `GridBagLayout` constraints. These constraints are predefined in the class `TableLayoutCell`. One of these predefined constraints is `weighty`, which is set to the value 0. This means that the panel/table will be always centered vertically.